# How to save project to filesystem you've SSHed into?

Tags: ssh

I've used `ssh` to connect to a remote filesystem from my local machine. I have a project saved on my local system that I want to test on the remote system. I want to transfer the project from my local system to the remote system I've SSHed into.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use scp:

`scp -r /local/directory/ username@remote_host:/remote/directory/`

Comment: Note that `scp` should be installed on the local system.